# Django object creation and Postgres Sequences

Tags: django, postgresql

I have an import script which runs a series of commands to get things from one Postgres DB to another, both running the same Django codebase. For the most part, it uses ./manage.py loaddata to copy over, but some objects require additional processing and I use Django's objects.create() method in a custom script to copy the data. When doing this, I specify the ID, i.e,

```
MyObject.objects.create(id = 2, title = 'foo')
```

Once the script is done, I'm noticing that the Postgres SEQUENCE is wrong on the tables where I did objects.create(). I.e., it was 50 before the import, and still 50 after, even though the table now has 150 objects. This, of course, leads to errors when creating new objects, since it tries to use an ID which already exists (On all these tables, the ID is just a vanilla auto-increment field). However, the tables which were filled via ./manage.py loaddata seem fine.

I'm aware that I can manually reset these tables with Django's ./manage.py sqlsequenreset, but I'm curious as to why the sequence seems to get out of whack in the first place. Does objects.create() not increment it? Am I overlooking something obvious?

Comment: aren't there better ways to sync database? Did you check structure of table about auto increment in id field?

Comment: I am not up to date with postgres-specific stuff, but my guess is, that whenever a row is inserted with a `null` for an identity column, it gets "filled in" by postgres (a la auto_increment) and the sequence is incremented. If you specify an id by yourself, it bypasses this logic and just inserts the row directly. I guess, that django makes no attempt at actually incrementing the sequence number, leaving it to the database engine.

Comment: @shylent I'm also flying on intuition here, but it seems like the purpose of having a sequence variable incremented in the database is to avoid having to run a max over the ids for each record on every insert when the id is not specified.  To keep the sequence up to date in the OP's use case, a max would have to be run after every insert when the id is specified.  I think it's justified to require the user to manually request the refresh.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

everything works fine. django's create() has nothing to do with sequence incementation directly. briefly:

- postgresql auto incrementing
  ('serial' type) is just a shortcut of
  'create sequence + create integer
  field with sequence value as default'
- django's autofield primary key (id
  integer if not specified else by you)
  just creates a serial field
- when you specify the id manually,
  postgres inserts the value into the
  database. when you specify a value,
  it omits the 'default' parameter,
  which is a proper behavior.

so, if you want your inserts to increment the sequence in a way of your choice, you need to manually change the sequence value using SELECT setval('sequence_name', int_value); otherwise leave it null and it will increment automatically - select the current val and increment it +1 (if not specified differently in the sequence definition).

another idea is you create the object and then update the id (of course it can't be already used) and in the end set the sequence value to the max id.

Answer (score 2):

The autoincrement fields works, but yo must make the query like

```
MyObject.objects.create(title='foo')
```

without the id field, this is autocalculated with the database.

Comment: I guess what I'm curious about here is that the JSON produced by Django's own dumpdata command specifies the PKs of the objects, and the loaddata command seems to honor those PKs without the Postgre sequence getting messed up. So why does objects.create fail to do so?

Maybe it's simply an oversight?

Comment: @KRH i think this code in `django/core/management/commands/load.py:188` can explain us that question.

Comment: Got it. I guess I'm somewhat surprised that objects.create() doesn't do this considering the primary key errors it can spawn, but I suppose that from a design perspective they consider it to be the users' problem to solve.